# paypal invalid negative testing input

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I try to simulate negative testing using paypal rest sdk with nodejs based on [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/nt-rest/)

Hier is my code implementation:

```
config.headers = {
 "PayPal-Mock-Response": {"mock_application_codes":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED"}
}

paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, data, config, function (error, payment) {
if (error) {
        console.log(error.response);

    } else {
        // success code
    }
}});
```

However I got this following error:

```
{ name: 'SIMULATION_FRAMEWORK_INVALID_NEGATIVE_TESTING_INPUT',message:'Invalid input found. See the following supported cases.',links: [ { href: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/nt-rest/',rel: 'information_link' } ],details: [ { issue: 'You must have valid input.' } ],httpStatusCode: 400 }
```

Can anyone help me what's wrong from my code?

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You have to stringify the object:

```
headers: {
            'PayPal-Mock-Response': JSON.stringify({
                "mock_application_codes":"CANNOT_PAY_SELF"
            })
        },
```